# Regular expression to remove special characters from start or end of a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove special characters from start or end of string,

```
@Can't&
```

Using regular expression and I've tired,

```
`[^\w\s]`
```

But this  regular expression removes `'` which is inside the word and return below word,

```
Cant
```

Can't seem to wrap my head around this any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be simplified like this:

```
  res = re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following approach (using regex alternation `..|..`):

```
import re

s = "@Can't&"
res = re.sub(r'^[^\w\s]+|[^\w\s]+$', '', s)
print(res)    # Can't
```